# The OnSuccess method responds after the activity finishes to fill a spinner control

Tags: java, android, loopj

Hello software developers.

I'm developing an android application that consumes a REST service so I'm using the Http Client Library (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), but I want to populate a spinner control so I first call to the method fillSpinnerTiposSiniestros and populate an ArrayList to later use that ArrayList to fill the adapter of the spinner, but I do not know why the adapter is first established and then called the REST client, so the spinner remains empty.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit_sinister);

    editTextValorClave = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorClave);
    editTextValorCurp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorCurp);
    editTextValorDependencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorDependencia);
    editTextValorRFC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorRFC);
    editTextValorStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorStatus);
    //editTextValorTipoSiniestro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorTipoSiniestro);
    spinnerTipoSiniestro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoSiniestro);

    editTextValorNumAmbulancia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterNumAmbulancia);
    editTextValorNombreSieniestro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterNombreSieniestro);
    editTextValorLocalizacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSinisterValorLocalizacion);
    textViewMuestraEncabezado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitulo);

    botonAccionAddEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSinisterAddEdit);
    botonAccionAddEdit.setOnClickListener(eventoAccionBotonAddEdit);

    Bundle miBlunde = getIntent().getExtras();

    opcion = miBlunde.getInt("Opcion");
    claveGlobal = miBlunde.getInt("Clave");

    CargarDatosSpinner;
}

private void rellenarSpinnerTiposSiniestros(){
    List<Header> encabezados = new ArrayList<Header>();
    encabezados.add(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));


    SiniestroRESTClient.get(AddEditSinisterActivity.this, "api/TipoSiniestro", encabezados.toArray(new Header[encabezados.size()]), null,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response)
                {
                    arrayTipoSiniestro = new ArrayList<TipoSiniestro>();
                    tipoSiniestroAdapter = new SpinnerTipoSiniestroAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, (TipoSiniestro[]) arrayTipoSiniestro.toArray());

                    for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            tipoSiniestroAdapter.add(new TipoSiniestro(response.getJSONObject(i)));
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    tipoSiniestroAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerTipoSiniestro.setAdapter(tipoSiniestroAdapter);
                }
            });
}
```

I tried with this solution [asynchttpclient gives response after activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301157/asynchttpclient-onsuccess-method-gives-response-after-activity-is-finished), but I have an exception like:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                            Process: com.maestria.lostperson, PID: 13433
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.
>                                                                                at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.sendRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:1493)
>                                                                                at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:1095)
>                                                                                at com.maestria.lostperson.clients.SiniestroRESTClient.get(SiniestroRESTClient.java:24)
>                                                                                at com.maestria.lostperson.AddEditSinisterActivity$2.doInBackground(AddEditSinisterActivity.java:159)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to touch UI components from background thread. Just add the:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             arrayTipoSiniestro = new ArrayList<TipoSiniestro>();
                tipoSiniestroAdapter = new SpinnerTipoSiniestroAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, (TipoSiniestro[]) arrayTipoSiniestro.toArray());

                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tipoSiniestroAdapter.add(new TipoSiniestro(response.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                tipoSiniestroAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerTipoSiniestro.setAdapter(tipoSiniestroAdapter);
        }
    });
```

around your response. Or handle it with creating a Handler before you call the async method and use the Handler on your return. Whichever you prefer is fine. It's not heavy enough to have a strong preference one way or the other.

Comment: I just did lol. I supplied you the code above, just move your code inside the block. Here I will update.

Comment: Then put this whole blurb inside the onSuccess